# Combine two ActiveRecord::Relation returning a Relation and not an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Suppose I have the following two objects:

```rb
relation_1 = Company.select("companies.company_code, event_contracts.company_name").left_joins(:event_contract)
relation_1 = Company.select("companies.company_code, event_plans.content").left_joins(:event_plans)
```

I tried merge two objects but it returns `an Array` and `not Relation`.

```rb
companies = relation_1 + relation_2
companies.class
=> Array
```

```rb
companies = relation_1.or(relation_2)
=> ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:select, :joins]
```

Is it possible to combine the two relations to produce one ActiveRecord::Relation object?

This is my model

```rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_contracts
  has_many :event_plans
end

class EventContract < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
end

class EventPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
end
```

Comment: i use ruby 2.6.5

Comment: This is an [X&Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) as you're asking about a broken solution instead of the actual problem you're trying to solve. The real answer here is not to merge the two different queries - its a completely different query and/or assocation. Please instead show us your models and what the desired output is.

Comment: The reason this attempt is broken is that `students.*` would select all the columns off that table so columns that exist on both tables like `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` would be wildly ambiguous (is it persons.id or students.id?) and its not permitted in many databases. I also don't see why you don't simply use an assocation and eager load it.

Comment: That doesn't really help us answer your question. Please edit the question and add your models and the expected result.

Comment: The relation between Company and EventContract is one to many. Selecting `event_contracts.company_name` is wildly ambigous and is also not permitted in for example Postgres. Which one is it that you want? The first one? The last one? All of them? You would need to use an aggregate function like `ARRAY_AGG` or `JSON_AGG` together with GROUP. The same applies to EventContract.

Comment: @max `company_name` is column of `event_contracts`.
I want to all company from event_contract and from event_plan(All of them)

Comment: I guess it is permitted on MySQL though that will allow you to select non-aggregated columns from the join tables and returns a row for each combo (which is batshit crazy imho). I would just eager load both the assocations instead.

Comment: in this case, company has two names, origin name(`company.name`) and contract name(`event_contract.company_name`) @@

Comment: Actually, i want to get all record of company left_join event_contract and all record of company left_join event_plan

Answer (score 0):

you could just combine the select and the joins.

```rb
Person.select("persons.p_code, 
               students.name, 
               teachers.name, 
               teachers.salary, 
               teachers.updated_at as latest_updated_at")
  .left_joins(:student, :teacher)
```